# Java loop for reading multiple URL's is slowing down

Tags: java

I have written some code to comb through approximately 10000 web pages on a website to put together a profile of the user demographics on the website.  The basis of the program is to read each line of the source code of the website, parse out the data wanted, then move onto the next page.

I am encountering an issue where around the 650th page or so, the program goes from reading around 3 pages per second to 1 page per 10-15 seconds.  It always occurs at the same point of the program execution.  I began wondering if this might be a memory issue with my program and begin to check each aspect of it.  Eventually I stripped the program down to its basics:

Step 1) Create an array of URL objects.

Step 2) Loop through the array and open/close a buffered reader to read each line.

Step 3) Read the entire page and move onto the next line.

Even this slowed down in the exact spot, so this isn't a problem with the data I am parsing or where I am storing it.  It is a result of this loop somehow.  I am wondering if there is a memory issue with what I have written that is causing issues?  Otherwise my only guess is somehow I am making calls too quickly to the website servers and it is intentionally slowing me down.

**Obviously not the best written code, as I am new and subject to a bunch of sloppy coding.  But it does execute perfectly what I want.  The issue is it slows down to a crawl after about ten minutes, which won't work.

Here is the relevant code:

**Array code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class UrlArrayBuild {

private int page_count; //number of pages 
public URL[] urlArray;  //array of webpage url's

    public UrlArrayBuild(int page) { //object constructor
        page_count = page; //initializes page_count
        urlArray = new URL[page_count]; //initializes page_count
    }

    protected void buildArray() throws IOException { // method assigns strings to   UrlArray object
        int count; //counter for iteration
        for(int i = 0; i < page_count; i++) { //loops through 
            count = i * 60; //sets user number at end of page
            URL website = new URL("http://...." + count);
            urlArray[i] = website; //url address
            //System.out.println(urlArray[i]); //debug
        }
    }

    protected URL returnArrayValue(int index) {  //method returns string value in array of given index
        //System.out.println(urlArray[index]); //debug
        return urlArray[index];
    }

    protected int returnArrayLength() { //method returns length of array
        //System.out.println(urlArray.length); //debug
        return urlArray.length;

    }

}
```

**Reader Code**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DataReader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    UrlArrayBuild PrimaryArray = new UrlArrayBuild(9642); //Creates array object
    PrimaryArray.buildArray();  //Builds array 

    //Create and initialize variables to use in loop
    URL website = null;  
    String inputLine = null;

            //Loops through array and reads source code
    for (int i = 0; i < PrimaryArray.returnArrayLength(); i++) {

        try {
            website = PrimaryArray.returnArrayValue(i);  //acquires url
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(website.openStream()));  //reads url source code
            System.out.println(PrimaryArray.returnArrayValue(i));  //prints out website url.  I use it as a check to monitor progress
            while((inputLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                if (inputLine.isEmpty()) { //checks for blank lines
                    continue;
                } else {
                    //begin parsing code.  This is currently commented so there is nothing that occurs here
                }
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } finally {
             //extraneous code here currently commented out.  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some delays cause by websites themselved epspecially if they are rich in term of contents. This might be a reason.
Parsing also can be factor in some delays. Therefore, personally I suggest to useful library for parsing that might be better optimized.
Good luck!

Comment: I wondered if it might be the website itself doing this.  Like I said I removed all the code that does the parsing.  All the program currently does is read each line of the source code and then move onto another webpage.  After ~600 times doing this the rate goes from 3 pages a second to 1 page per 10 seconds.  Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

1. Multithread the application so requests can run concurrently. Or,
2. Rearchitect to use asynchronous IO / HTTP requests. Netty or MINA, or possibly just raw NIO.

Both of these related solutions are a lot of work, but a sophisticated solution is unfortunately required to deal with your problem. Basically, asynchronous frameworks exist to solve exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think when looping through array, you can use multi-threading technologies and asynchronized java method invocation to improve your performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obviously wrong with your code that would explain this.  Certainly not in the code that you have shown us.  Your code is not saving anything that is being read so it can't be leaking memory that way.  And it shouldn't leak resources ... because if there are any I/O exceptions, the application terminates immediately.

(However, if your code did attempt to continue after I/O exceptions, then you would need to move the `close()` call into the `finally` block to avoid the socket / file descriptor leakage.)

It is most likely either it is a server-side or (possibly) network issue:

- Look to see if there something unusual about the pages at around the 650 page mark.  Are they bigger?  Do they entail extra server-side processing (meaning they will be delivered more slowly)?
- Look at the server-side load (while the application is running) and its log files.
- Check to see if some kind of server request throttling has been implemented; e.g. as an anti-DoS measure.
- Check to see if some kind of network traffic throttling has been implemented.
- Also check on the client-side resource usage.  I would expect CPU usage to either stay constant, or tail off at the 650 page mark.  If CPU usage *increases*, that would cast suspicion back onto the application.